# Understanding the Dump for w3p app with WinDbg

Tags: windbg, dump, crash-dumps

This is my first time looking into WinDbg.
We have one of our servers getting into a weird state regularly (once a month). The "weird state" - is that the application that processes the requests thinks there is not enough storage left, when there should be more than plenty.
The issue seems to be related to w3p process. To get more details to help us analyse the potential root cause - we have collected a Dump file for the w3p process.
But reading the dump file (using the latest version of WinDbg) - does not give me any hint at all.
Can anyone please help me to understand this?

Here is the analysis of the dump file:

```
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
   ExtensionRepository : Implicit
   UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : false
   AllowNugetExeUpdate : false
   AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : false
   AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

   -- Configuring repositories
      ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
      ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.016 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.016 seconds
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 36

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25921.1001 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\user1\Downloads\w3wp\w3wp.DMP]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 14393 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer DataCenter SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 10.0.14393.6343 (rs1_release.230913-1727)
Debug session time: Wed Dec 20 04:10:12.000 2023 (UTC - 8:00)
System Uptime: 22 days 5:04:36.302
Process Uptime: 0 days 6:05:14.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.......................................
Loading unloaded module list
..........................................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14:
00007ffa`11625ea4 c3              ret
0:000> .sympath SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3721436

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 3732286

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 1

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1061

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 24185

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 1576

    Key  : CLR.BuiltBy
    Value: NET48REL1LAST_B

    Key  : CLR.Engine
    Value: CLR

    Key  : CLR.Version
    Value: 4.8.4645.0

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: BREAKPOINT_80000003_w3wphost.dll!AppHostInitialize

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {c8bd1ff0-1550-3c6c-7435-bfa31a670998}

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 1919076

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 21914

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: rs1_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.14393.6343

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 10.0.14393.0


FILE_IN_CAB:  w3wp.DMP

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  0002f848

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
00000025`8cfdf5f8 00007ffa`0e366d1f     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
00000025`8cfdf600 00007ff9`fec818ac     : 00000204`1ffaa6a0 00000025`8cfdf740 00007ff6`00000000 00000000`000001f4 : KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8f
00000025`8cfdf6a0 00007ff6`abb1156e     : 00000000`fffffffe 00000204`1ffa6a40 00000204`1ffa6a40 00007ff9`fec80000 : w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+0x14c
00000025`8cfdf6e0 00007ff6`abb12dcd     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : w3wp!wmain+0x412
00000025`8cfdf880 00007ffa`0eec84d4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : w3wp!__wmainCRTStartup+0x14d
00000025`8cfdf8c0 00007ffa`115d1791     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000025`8cfdf8f0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+14c

MODULE_NAME: w3wphost

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wphost.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_w3wphost.dll!AppHostInitialize

OS_VERSION:  10.0.14393.6343

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.14393.2339

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c8bd1ff0-1550-3c6c-7435-bfa31a670998}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

**UPDATED** (based on some suggestions).

Here is the Hang analysis output, which seems to provide even less info:

```
0:000> .sympath SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0:000> !analyze -hang
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+14c

MODULE_NAME: w3wphost

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wphost.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_w3wphost.dll!AppHostInitialize

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {9f08a9ce-8bf0-138e-28fb-0c706c2e5fa0}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 00000025`8cfdf5f8 00007ffa`0e366d1f     ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
01 00000025`8cfdf600 00007ff9`fec818ac     KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8f
02 00000025`8cfdf6a0 00007ff6`abb1156e     w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+0x14c
03 00000025`8cfdf6e0 00007ff6`abb12dcd     w3wp!wmain+0x412
04 00000025`8cfdf880 00007ffa`0eec84d4     w3wp!__wmainCRTStartup+0x14d
05 00000025`8cfdf8c0 00007ffa`115d1791     kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
06 00000025`8cfdf8f0 00000000`00000000     ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Comment: You should hire an experienced consultant to help review your event logs and the dump(s). It is unrealistic to expect learning such a complex technique via Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unless you can explain what's the "weird state" (deadlocks, mem leaks, mem retention, etc.) shown by the process, it's going to be hard to help you (and without the dump it is going to extra hard). `w3wp` is certainly going to be a process with a high thread count and we only have one waiting thread (nothing out of the ordinary here). Edit: I concur with @LexLi, unless you can pinpoint the problem by yourself, we can't do much. Hiring someone to determine the root cause might be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks folks. Since my knowledge of the dump is almost null, thus I was hoping it could be readable by someone with a bit more experience. But I guess we will have to solve this ourselves then. And the "weird" issue we're experiencing is that once a month one of the servers cannot process the requests forwarded to it and complains it does not have enough space (while it should have more than plenty). Since it usually processes 10s of thousands of requests - it would be really hard to figure out what and why is causing this. And I was hoping that a crash-dump could lead us to some hint.

Comment: You have a breakpoint, which means that the process was not crashing, but you have taken a dump manually. The main thread is in `AppHostInitialize`, which could mean that it is starting up. `NtWaitForSingleObject` means that it's waiting for something. Maybe it's in a deadlock. For a deadlock analysis, try `!analyze -hang`. Other than that, looking at the call stack is typically helpful, try `k`.

Comment: And then, well, with no prior knowledge on dump analysis, this will be too hard for you as the first dump. Try simpler examples to become familiar with WinDbg, e.g. examine a crash in a console application, deadlock in a console app, deadlock in WinForms, then a crash in a Webapp, deadlock in a webapp. All with most basic code, like 20 lines.